# how to understand this p-values in jointplot?

Tags: python

I am not sure how to understand this p value from jointplot. the pearson correlation coefficient is pretty high 0.74. but why p-value is almost zero. what does this p value means? Thanks

```
from scipy import stats
sns.jointplot(df_Shale['Proppant Loading'], df_Shale['EUR'],color='blue',kind='kde',stat_func=stats.pearsonr )
```

[image]

Comment: It means that if the actual correlation coefficient were zero it would be very unlikely to get a correlation coefficient of 0.74 with this data set -- therefore, you have statistical evidence to say these two variables are correlated.

Comment: Thank you Sir! so the hypothesis is always opposite to the goal? Thanks